# Number variables appear in directory when I run bash script

Tags: shell-script, ls, variable

I have written a Bash script in a directory. When I run it and then run 'ls' a number appears in the directory level which I must then use 'rm' to get rid of.

This Bash script is meant to save the current files in the directory to `logstore.txt` then get the old number of lines stored in `numlines.txt` then find the new number of lines assigning this to `numlines.txt` and finally getting the new number of lines to compare to the old number (the server is adding new files over time if you couldn't guess) I then run a comparison between the old and new line lengths.

Here is the code in a .sh file.

```
ls /home/vcm > /home/vcm/logstore.txt
oldnumlines=$(cat /home/vcm/numlines.txt)
#log store takes the new ls of items and stores it as num lines after the old v$
cat logstore.txt | wc -l > /home/vcm/numlines.txt

newnumlines=$(cat /home/vcm/numlines.txt)

if [ ! "$newnumlines" > "$oldnumlines" ]
#[ "$a" -eq "$b" ]
#(( "$newnumlines" -le "$oldnumlines" ))
 then
   *do something*
 fi
```

Why is this script creating new variables in the directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to debug something like this. I have a simplified version of your script.

```
$ cat var_dumper.bash
#!/bin/bash

var1=1
var2=2

if [ ! "$var1" > "$var2" ]; then
   echo "I'm inside the if/then"
fi
```

And we run it:

```
$ ./var_dumper.bash
$ ls
var_dumper.bash  2
```

So we can see your `2` showing up as a file. That's your issue.

#### Debugging

To debug a shell script, I always start with the `-x` switch to Bash. You can run your script like this:

```
$ bash -x ./var_dumper.bash
+ var1=1
+ var2=2
+ '[' '!' 1 ']'
```

This tells us where it's failing. The `if` condition. So what's wrong with it? Well the first clue should be the `>`. That's a redirect operator, in other usages in Bash, so that's what's likely producing the file being written.

So let's reformulate your example into a single executable:

```
$ var1=1 var2=2 [ "$var1" > "$var2" ] && echo success || echo failure
success
```

The next clue should be, why is it returning a success, 1 isn't greater than 2. So we google and we discover that to compare integers in Bash you don't use the `>` operator, you're actually suppose to use this one: `-gt`.

```
$ var1=1 var2=2 [ "$var1" -gt "$var2" ] && echo success || echo failure
failure
```

And since you originally wanted it negated, we could put the `!` back in:

```
$ var1=1 var2=2 [ ! "$var1" -gt "$var2" ] && echo success || echo failure
success
```

And it works. So your corrected `if` statement would look like this:

```
if [ ! "$var1" -gt "$var2" ]; then
   echo "I'm inside the if/then"
fi
```

#### So what was wrong with `>`

In your scenario you were using `if [ .... ]`. This form of if/then is the POSIX compliant version. This one does not support the `>` operator. The form that does support that is this, `if [[ .... ]]`.  The double bracketed version is the more capable *extended test* command.

So as an alternative:

```
$ cat var_dumper.bash
#!/bin/bash

var1=1
var2=2

if [[ ! "$var1" > "$var2" ]]; then
   echo "I'm inside the if/then"
fi
```

Would also work:

```
$ bash -x var_dumper.bash
+ var1=1
+ var2=2
+ [[ ! 1 > 2 ]]
+ echo 'I'\''m inside the if/then'
I'm inside the if/then
```

#### References

- [7.3. Other Comparison Operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use **>** in a digital test. Because it is a redirection operator.

His execution is always true (if the file is written) :

```
$ if [ 2 > 30000 ]; then echo OK; else echo NO; fi
OK
$ ls
$ 30000
$ rm 30000
```

And a 30000  file was written.

There was no digital test but a file write, which returned true

```
$ mkdir tmp
$ chmod -w tmp
$ cd tmp
$ if [ 2 > 30000 ]; then echo OK; else echo NO; fi
-bash: 30000: Permission non accordée
NO
$ cd ..
$ rmdir tmp
```

Use -gt :

```
$ if [ 2 -gt 30000 ]; then echo OK; else echo NO; fi
NO
$ ls
```